# How to loop through the value from the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to find manager name of employees from this table (There are certain users in the table who are managers and for them emp_mgr would be null where as employees under a particular manager it would be populated by manager's employee number

```
  CREATE TABLE EMP (
     EMP_NUM        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
     EMP_TITLE  CHAR(10),   
     EMP_LNAME  VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
     EMP_FNAME  VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
     EMP_INITIAL    CHAR(1),
     EMP_DOB        DATETIME,
     EMP_HIRE_DATE  DATETIME,
     EMP_AREACODE   CHAR(3),
     EMP_PHONE  CHAR(8),
     EMP_MGR        INTEGER);
```

I tried to look for employees who are managers using the below one but I am unable to do

```
select * from EMP where emp_mgr='' (I am unable to get the data) This is because Managers have no emp_mgr and it would be generally null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a self-join:

```
SELECT e1.emp_num, e1.emp_lname as employee_last_name, e2.emp_lname as manager_last_name
from emp e1
LEFT JOIN emp e2 ON e1.emp_mgr = e2.emp_num
```

When the employee is a manager, the e2 values will be NULL

Comment: Addead a where condition so that it displays only employees

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. if you just want a list of the top managers (with no other manager) then this:

```
select * from EMP where emp_mgr is null;
```

you might also nest things, like this:

```
select * from emp where emp_num in ( select emp_mgr from emp );
```